# Failure occurred putting a message to the queue manager

Tags: ibm-mq

While publishing the message, I am getting this exception as "Failure occurred putting a message to the queue manager"

Failure occured putting a message to the queue manager

MQRC 2488

Subscription is also seems to be fine in queue manager for the topic string, which is being published by the flow. No selector function in subscription.

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What version of WebSphere MQ are you using? and what client are you using to publish the message?

Comment: Can you double check the MQRC number you got. 2488 is MQRC_OPERATION_ERROR which occurs when using MQCB or MQCTL - a getting message verb - nothing to do with putting messages.